# Одномерные массивы;c++

Tags: c++, c, вывод

В одномерном массиве, состоящем из п целых элементов, вычислить:
1.  Номер максимального элемента массива;
2. Произведение элементов массива, расположенных между первым и вторым нулевыми элементами.
3. Преобразовать массив таким образом, чтобы в первой его половине располагались элементы, стоявшие в нечетных позициях, а во второй половине -элементы, стоявшие в четных позициях.
Исходный код:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
main(){
int i,A[i],nMax=0,count=0,m,k,s,l,f;
printf("Input massive\n");
for(i=0;i<m;i++){
printf("Input:%n>",i);
scanf("%d",&A[i]);
}
for(i=1;i<m;i++)
    if(A[i]>A[nMax])
    nMax=i;
    printf("\nMax element:(%d)=%d",nMax+1,A[nMax]);
}
     for(i=l+i;i<f;i++)
        s=s*a[i];            
        cout<<"\nProizvedenie elementov mejdu pervim i vtorim nulevimi elementami\n"<<s;
        cout<<"\nPreobrazavanii massiv:"<<endl<<
{
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
if(i%2==0)
cout<<" "<<a[i];
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
if(i%2!=0)
cout<<" "<<a[i];
}
```

Результаты выполнения программы:

```
16  E:\Programare\lab2C.cpp [Error] expected unqualified-id before 'for'
16  E:\Programare\lab2C.cpp [Error] 'i' does not name a type
18  E:\Programare\lab2C.cpp [Error] 'cout' does not name a type
19  E:\Programare\lab2C.cpp [Error] 'cout' does not name a type
```

Comment: Убери в начале "вариант 7" иначе точно закроют вопрос

Comment: И вообще переделай текст, тут не любят домашние работы, напиши так, какбудто сам хотел решить эту задачу, но не получилось.

Comment: У вас задача еще в том, чтобы демонстрировать способ вывода и через  printf и через  cout? Зачем вам  <stdio.h> если есть  <iostream>?

Comment: Метка С не в тему. Ещё и виглядит как дз.

Answer (score 1):

Отформатируем ваш текст (что я очень, *очень*, **очень** рекомендую делать всегда - иначе сами запутаетесь. Что и произошло...):

```
using namespace std;
main()
{
    int i, A[i], nMax = 0, count = 0, m, k, s, l, f;
    printf("Input massive\n");

    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        printf("Input:%n>", i);
        scanf("%d", &A[i]);
    }

    for (i = 1; i < m; i++)
        if (A[i] > A[nMax])
            nMax = i;

    printf("\nMax element:(%d)=%d", nMax + 1, A[nMax]);
}

for (i = l + i; i < f; i++)
    s = s * a[i];

cout << "\nProizvedenie elementov mejdu pervim i vtorim nulevimi elementami\n"
     << s;
cout << "\nPreobrazavanii massiv:" << endl <<
{
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        if (i % 2 == 0)
            cout << " " << a[i];

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        if (i % 2 != 0)
            cout << " " << a[i];
}
```

Ну как, теперь видно, что у вас просто скобки не сбалансированы?

Далее, ну что за смесь французского с нижегородским? С с С++? Или `printf`, или `cout`. Или, росто сперев чужую программу на С, вы попытались, де думая и не понимая, что-то к ней дописать - авось прокатит?

При `main()` нужно бы `int` написать.

Вот тут - что вы выводить собрались после `endl`?

```
cout<<"\nPreobrazavanii massiv:"<<endl<<
{
```

P.S. И еще - у вас результат **не выполнения** программы, а ее **компиляции**.

Comment: После чего? Как внесли какие-то новые ошибки? Вы не пытайтесь методом чукотского ученого Тыка работать, а ДУМАЙТЕ. Очень умн*О* - что-то наваять свое, не показать и выкатить претензию - не работает! И не будет. Вы же не хотите главное - думать! Так что мой совет - открывайте кошелек и [сюда](http://www.reshaem.net/?cGFydG5lcj03OTIy) - тут без проблем сделают все, что вам нужно, вам останется только сдать - судя по всему, вам это важнее, чем знать.